# Можно ли вывести массив за пределы цикла в PHP?

Tags: php, массивы, циклы, foreach

Можно ли вывести массив за пределы цикла foreach?

Вывожу массив за пределы цикла и соот. получаю последнею ячейку массива.

Если вывести значение массива в переменную то получаю весь массив в виде строки.

А задача как раз в том, что бы выводить все данные поочередно, как в цикле. Это возможно?

**UPD**

Есть цикл:

```
$categors = get_categories($args); 
foreach ($categors as $categor){ 
    $options = get_option("taxonomy_" . $categor->slug); 
    $bgcolor = ' style="background-color: ' . esc_attr($options['color']) . ';"'; 
}
```

Хочу вывести ниже `$bgcolor` поочередно

```
if(!($this->tw_type==='post'&&$depth>1)){
    $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names . $bgcolor .'>';
}
```

, но получается либо последний элемент массива вывести строкой, либо в переменную строкой весь массив полностью

Comment: array_walk() http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-walk.php или array_map(). Там еще справа куча функций с описанием.

Comment: `Можно ли вывести массив за пределы цикла foreach?`, `Вывожу массив за пределы цикла и соот. получаю последнею ячейку массива.` - что значат эти магические фразы?

Comment: Есть цикл: `$categors = get_categories($args);

        foreach ($categors as $categor){
            $options = get_option("taxonomy_" . $categor->slug);
            $bgcolor = ' style="background-color: ' . esc_attr($options['color']) . ';"';
        }` Хочу вывести ниже $bgcolor поочередно `if(!($this->tw_type==='post'&&$depth>1)){$output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names . $bgcolor .'>';}` , но получается либо последний элемент массива вывести строкой, либо в переменную строкой весь массив полностью

Comment: А если сделать ещё один цикл, в котором всё и вывести поочерёдно?